# Check LDAP emails from given email list

Tags: node.js, email, ldap

I have a list of emails and am trying to make a Node.js script that checks the list of emails from the LDAP Server. I'm trying to find out how many users are inactive from the LDAP Server and to return an array of them. I just can't take the list of emails from LDAP. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i tried to work with Active Directory and specifically with ad.findUser, but when i pass as a query='mail = *example.com' it did not return valid emails

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution and I want to provide it for helping other programmers.
I used the Active Directory module and userExists function:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

var config = {
url: 'ldap://my.ldap.com:389', //use ldaps://my.ldap.com:636 for secure connection
baseDN: 'ou=users, o=example.com',
uid: 'myusername',
password: 'mypassword'
}
var active_dir = new ActiveDirectory(config);

//read list of emails from csv file

var readline = readline.createInterface({
input: require('fs').createReadStream('email_list.csv')
});

readline.on('line', function (line) {

active_dir.userExists(every_line, function(err, exists) {
    if (err) {
        throw (err);
    }
    console.log( every_line + ' exists: ' + exists);
           }); 
    });
```